# Insert content between sections in WP customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options

Is it possible to insert some HTML content between sections in WP Customizer?

E.g.it can be used for further sectioning
[image]

Comment: Inserting content _between_ sections is not supported. So the closest thing you can do create a custom section template, similar to how you can see the Themes section has custom content inside of its label.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you add HTML to a WordPress Theme Customizer

https://coreymckrill.com/2014/01/09/adding-arbitrary-html-to-a-wordpress-theme-customizer-section/

Comment: It adds to section, but I want to add between sections though

Comment: you want to add new options in Customizer ?

Comment: No, to add content between sections, as in screenshot.